# Can't fix error: Cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBindingImpl

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

I've got following error while trying to build prject with MVVM and data binding. I've searched through everything I could find here on StackOverflow, or common mistakes on the internet, but nothing worked for my case. 
The only message I receive is this error. It looks like this in `buildOutput`:
[image]

I've had my packages named with capital letters and I've found here that this might be the cause because compiler treat them as names of classes, so I've changed them all to start with small letters, but that haven't helped.
I've created `ViewModelFactory` for creating my `ViewModel` inside `Activity` so I could send additional parameters with constructor using factory, so I've tried to remove it and use no parameters and create instance without using factory for this purpose, but still I havn't got any results (same error)
I was chaning both `build.gradle`'s in different ways but result was always the same.
Finally I've deleted data binding and variable from XML, then I was able to run the app (with other errors, but I would be probably able to deal with those by myself) but I want to leave it as it is and just deal with my error. 
I am not experienced with MVVM and data binding so it can be just a stupid mistake, but it is hard to find it if I don't know where I should look for it.
Here I post most important codes, if you need more then let me know:
**build.grale(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rickmorty"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
}
```

**build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    lateinit var mAdapter: CharactersAdapter
    lateinit var api: CharacterAPI

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
        api = retrofit.create(CharacterAPI::class.java)
        setupViewModel()
        setupRecycler()

        mainViewModel.getData().observe(this,
            Observer<List<Results>> { t ->
                mAdapter = CharactersAdapter(this@MainActivity, t!!)
                rvCharacters.adapter = mAdapter
            })
    }

    fun setupRecycler() {
        val lManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        rvCharacters.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = lManager
        }
        rvCharacters.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                val visibleItems = lManager.childCount
                val totalItems = lManager.itemCount
                val firstVisible = lManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                if (dy > 0) {
                    if (!mainViewModel.isLoading.value!! && (visibleItems + firstVisible) >= totalItems) {
                        mainViewModel.scrolledNext()
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!mainViewModel.isLoading.value!! && (totalItems - visibleItems) <= 0) {
                        mainViewModel.scrolledPrev()
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }

    fun setupViewModel() {
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, MainViewModelFactory(application, api))
            .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(
            this, R.layout.activity_main
        ).apply {
            lifecycleOwner = this@MainActivity
            viewmodel = mainViewModel
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.rickmorty.ViewModel.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlPageTitleHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@{() -> viewmodel.pageNumber}"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvCharacters"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rlPageTitleHolder"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.9"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

As I wrote earlier, after removing `variable` from XML and binding from `MainActivity` error disappears.
I know it is a lot of code, so if something is redundant just let me know. There is factory class still missing, but I will post it if it's necessary. Also `MainRepo` is one I haven't attached here, but it's quite long, but I can post it all if you're gonna need it.

Comment: Clean-rebuild please

Comment: Did it lots of times. Cleaning, rebuilding, deleting `build` folder, invalidating cache and restarting. I've even created new project, copied whole code to it and tried to launch it then, because I though my project name is wrong because it contains special sign. Still same error. I've lost full day for this one error.

Comment: `android:text="@{viewmodel.pageNumber}"`

Comment: it is simplified name for `getPageNumber()` (Android Studio done this) but I have tried to switch it back to `@(() -> viewmodel.getPageNumber())` but that doesn't work too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the problem --> `android:text="@{() -> viewmodel.pageNumber}"`

correct syntax for assigning value using dataBinding is

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@{viewmodel.pageNumber}"/>
```